# Vue 3 ViTest files shows up all white with zero coverage

Tags: vuejs3, vitest, test-coverage

I have a test file, one of many, and hit has several described tests that all pass.
However, as you can see in the image, Vite Coverage says there is nothing there.
I do not know the cause of that.

[image]